# How to create dynamic table using html and java servlet?

Tags: java, html, mysql, servlets

I have a mysql table which stores tax information. Here is how it looks. [image]

Currently I am using html/servlet to display the table but in a very ineffective way as shown in this image below.

[image]

View tax information shows the table when there is value in the mysql table, as follows:

[image]

And if the user wishes to edit that, they must click the "Edit Tax Information" button which looks takes you to this:

[image]

Is there an effective way to do all this functionality? Simply like this:

[image]

Sample Code:

html:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>Add Tax Bracket</h1>
<form action ="AddTax" method = "post"> 


    <table border ="1"> 

    <tr>
    <td>Tax Bracket</td>
    <td><input type = "number" name = "bracket" min="0" step="1"  required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>From Salary($)</td>
    <td><input type = "number" name = "FromSalary" min="0" step="0.01"  required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>To Salary($)</td>
    <td><input type = "number" name = "ToSalary" min="0" step="0.01"  required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Tax Rate(%)</td>
    <td><input type = "number" name = "rate" min="0" step="0.01"  required></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Add Tax Bracket">
    </form>

    <h1>Remove Tax Bracket</h1>

    <form action ="RemoveTax" method = "post"> 
    <table border ="1"> 

    <tr>
    <td>Tax Bracket to remove</td>
    <td><input type = "number" name = "bracket1" min="0" step="1"  required></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Remove Tax Bracket">
    </form>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Servlet:

```
    String bracket = request.getParameter("bracket"); 
    String from = request.getParameter("FromSalary");
    String to = request.getParameter("ToSalary"); 
    String rate = request.getParameter("rate"); 

    try { 
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payroll_system.tax_info(TaxBracket, FromSalary, ToSalary, TaxPercentage) values(?,?,?,?)"); 
         ps.setString(1, bracket);
         ps.setString(2, from);
         ps.setString(3, to);
         ps.setString(4, rate);

         int count = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What's the question? _"Is there an effective way to do all this functionality"_ -- probably, but it's not clear what kind of assistance you need.  Is there something that doesn't work?  If you are asking about designing the user interface, the question is off-topic and belongs on [ux.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about user interface design and belongs on [ux.se]

Comment: your idea need alot of javascript